# Goal Seek Macro with Goal as a Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm grasping at straws here, so any help would be great (ie. I have no idea what I'm doing with VBA).

I'm trying to solve a circular reference problem in Excel by creating a goal seek macro - basically

1. `S3 = M + S2`,
2. `S3 = L * G`.

I want to goal seek S3 to equal `L * G` by changing M.

So, I've put

- `L * G` in cell `H32`,
- `S3` in `H18`,
- `M` in `G18`,
- `S2` in `F18`

and this is what I've gathered so far.

```
Sub GoalSeek()   
Dim x As Integer
x = Range("H32").Value    
Range("H18").GoalSeek Goal:=x, ChangingCell:=Range("G18")     
End Sub
```

I'm getting a "Reference is not valid" error, ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GoalSeek will throw an "Invalid Reference" error if the GoalSeek cell contains a value rather than a formula or if the ChangingCell contains a formula instead of a value or nothing.

The GoalSeek cell must contain a formula that refers directly or indirectly to the ChangingCell; if the formula doesn't refer to the ChangingCell in some way, GoalSeek either may not converge to an answer or may produce a nonsensical answer.

I tested your code with a different GoalSeek formula than yours (I wasn't quite clear whether some of the terms referred to cells or values).

For the test, I set:

```
  the GoalSeek cell  H18 = (G18^3)+(3*G18^2)+6
  the Goal cell      H32 =  11
  the ChangingCell   G18 =  0
```

The code was:

```
Sub GSeek()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("H18").GoalSeek _
        Goal:=.Range("H32").Value, _
        ChangingCell:=.Range("G18")
    End With
End Sub
```

And the code produced the (correct) answer of 1.1038, the value of G18 at which the formula in H18 produces the value of 11, the goal I was seeking.

Comment: Thanks! I can follow the first part of this, but I think the reason my code is not working might be that my goal cell contains a formula and not a value??

Comment: Like ARIch, I think the problem must be that cell H18 doesn't contain a formula. I've added the code I used for my answer. This code works too:  
  Sub GSeek2()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Range("H32").Value
    Range("H18").GoalSeek Goal:=x, ChangingCell:=Range("G18")
  End Sub

Comment: To continue, the only times I could get GoalSeek to throw an invalid reference error was when the Goal cell did *not* contain a formula or when the ChangingCell *did* contain a formula.

Comment: Huh, not sure why I can't get this to work? I got your example to work (more or less, I got an answer of 1.007613 in G18 and 10.06887 in H18) but I still am lost as to why my code won't work. (I copy-pasted your above code, changing only the worksheet name, with no success.) H18 has the formula F18 + G18, where F18 contains a formula and G18 (the changing cell) contains a value. The goal cell H32 also contains a formula.

Comment: Wow, I feel ridiculous - I listened to your advice, and kept trying where the invalid reference was coming from - I put the changing cell as =value. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to make the cell references in the VBA code dynamic? For example, the H18 and H32 are hard coded above. Is there a way to pull that reference dynamically out of a cell. So instead of the formula, i can type H18 into a cell and this macro dynamically generates the same output as above.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that `Range("H18")` doesn't contain a formula. Also, you could make your code more efficient by eliminating `x`. Instead, change your code to

```
Range("H18").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("H32").Value, ChangingCell:=Range("G18")
```

Comment: Sorry, my original post was confusing - H18 (the goal seek cell) contains "=F18+G18" and the goal cell (H32) contains another formula. Is it possible to use a cell reference directly as the goal if it contains a formula and not a value?