# Goal Seek-esque macro without formulas in the Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that pulls columns of data from an external source, and a macro which then uses that data to calculate and populate other columns in the sheet. The calculation outputs on each row depend on the values of the row above. Ultimately, I would like to set the value of one column in the very last row to zero, by changing the input data in one of the first cells. If this were all Excel formulas then I could do a simple Goal Seek, but all of the calculations are carried out in vba.

I am new to vba so I'm not sure if what I'm asking is even possible. Here is an example of how my macro for the calculations looks:

```
Public Sub Calculate()

i = 2
Do While Cells(i, 3) <> ""

Cells(i, 31).Value = Cells(i, 30) / (1 + Cells(i, 61))
Cells(i, 28).Value = -Cells(i, 14) * Cells(i, 31) 
Cells(i, 27).Value = (-Cells(i, 26) * Cells(i, 2)) 
Cells(i, 32).Value = Cells(i, 15) + Cells(i, 2) + Cells(i,27) 
Cells(i, 29).Value = Cells(i, 61) * (Cells(i, 15) + Cells(i, 2) 
Cells(i, 61).Value = (Cells(i, 60) + 1) 
Cells(i, 62).Value = (Cells(18, 3) + 1) 
Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = Cells(i, 32) 
Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = Cells(i, 33) 

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Basically, the value of the last row of column 32 (AF) depends on the value of the first row of column 2 (B). So I would like to vary the value of B2 to make AF500 = 0, based on these calculations. I would love to avoid having formulas in the sheet so I hope this is possible. Thank you for taking the time to read, and sorry for the awful code.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to write "goal seek" in VBA, is that correct? I believe you can call goal seek via VBA. Related maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139322/goal-seek-macro-with-goal-as-a-formula

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed  Please say you've found all the `macro` tags now - I'm having trouble finding a new question on the home page. :)