# VBA - Goal Seek using variables, not using excel cells. Throws "invalid qualifier" error

Tags: excel, vba

My code below, simple goal-seek but using variables only, don't want to use excel cells. The goal-seek function throws the error "Invalid Qualifier".  I don't know why.  Please help?

```
Public Sub GoalSeekUsingArray()
      Dim a                   As Double
      Dim b                   As Double
      Dim c                   As Double
      Dim TotalCalculated     As Double
      Dim TotalDesired        As Integer

      a = 100
      b = -30
      c = -10
      TotalCalculated = a + b + c               '<<<<Initially... TotalCalculated = 60, as you can see.
      TotalDesired = 55                         '<<<<Goal-Seek should produce a=95 because 95 - 30 - 10 = 55 as desired goal.

      TotalCalculated.GoalSeek Goal:=TotalDesired, ChangingCell:=a   '<<<This throws the error.

      Debug.Print a

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you think a number (`TotalCalculated As Double`) has a method called `GoalSeek`? `GoalSeek` is a (hidden) method of `Range`, and it [must be used as such](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147581/11683).

Comment: Ok cannot use TotalCalculated as a variable.  How about using it as an array item?  Is that possible?  Can we say that an array item, such as myArray(4) can be used in place of a range?  myArray(1), myArray(2), myArray(3) are as presented a,b,c?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Presumably the changing cell needs to be a cell.

Comment: Hi everyone...been busy, sorry for late reply.  My objective for the question is this:  Goal-seek is so slow... I want to make it fast.  Fast = using array (not using cells/range)...agreed?  How to apply goal-seek using array (not using cells/range) to make it go fast?  If must use cells/range, then what is the answer to make goal-seek go fast?  5 seconds is too long!!  Thank you in advance!!